# Why is per_page not working with categories in WP API?

Tags: categories, api, rest-api

To start I've been searching through several questions and documentation pieces but it seems with WordPress' `v2` many of the old questions are no longer valid. What I am trying to do is get all posts or a singular post from a category in Postman instead of the common returned 10 posts without having to modify the API in functions.php.

### tldr

I started with referencing the [REST API Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) and reviewing the [schema](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#schema) I saw `categories` and I can return the 10 latest categories using:

```
http://foobar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/categories_name=hello
```

referencing the [arguments](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#arguments) I see `per_page` so I tried:

```
http://foobar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/categories_name=hello?per_page=‌​1
```

and it returns 10 posts from the category `hello` so I modified and tried:

```
http://foobar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/categories_name=hello&per_page=‌​1
```

and I get an error returned:

> {
>       "code": "rest_invalid_param",
>       "message": "Invalid parameter(s): per_page",
>       "data": {
>           "status": 400,
>           "params": {
>               "per_page": "per_page is not of type integer."
>           }
>       } }

Searching through Google I [see How to retrieve a list of categories/ tag in Wordpress REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20158417/how-to-retrieve-a-list-of-categories-tag-in-wordpress-rest-api) but the answers are based on `v1`.

Trying [Wordpress API JSON return limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29171854/wordpress-api-json-return-limit) I use:

```
http://foobar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?per_page=‌​1
```

and I get a singular post so I modified my attempt to:

```
http://foobar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?per_page=‌​1$categories_name=hello
```

It ignores the category type and returns the latest post. Reading [Get more than 10 posts in a specific category with the WordPress API](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/274890/get-more-than-10-posts-in-a-specific-category-with-the-wordpress-api) I pulled the ID of a category (4) after using:

```
http://foobar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories
```

then coded:

```
http://foobar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?categories=4&per_page=‌​1
```

and I get:

> {
>       "code": "rest_invalid_param",
>       "message": "Invalid parameter(s): per_page",
>       "data": {
>           "status": 400,
>           "params": {
>               "per_page": "per_page is not of type integer."
>           }
>       } }

I thought I might be able to use `-1` similar to the development of a theme but I get an error.

Other references I read are:

- [WP REST API - Retrieve content from page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/222547/wp-rest-api-retrieve-content-from-page)
- [WP REST API Category](http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/categories/)
- Found this [Since filter has been removed, how to get posts by category slug with same schema as v2/posts?](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/2949) after reading [Search post by categories Wordpress WP-API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38944843/search-post-by-categories-wordpress-wp-api)
- [How to get all posts related to particular category name?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40839/how-to-get-all-posts-related-to-particular-category-name)

After reviewing the documentation on [Pagination](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/#pagination-parameters) it seems to only work with the `post` and not any `category`.  I can only get more than 10 posts if I use `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=20`, too.

### Question

When calling a site's WP API how can I control the `per_page` return of a category wether it be 1 post or all posts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few hours trying different permutations of how to get a return on categories I found my answer.  To establish the listing of categories associated with `post` use:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/categories/
```

I needed a particular category and the `id` of that category was `4` and the slug was called `foobar`.

To get 1 post associated with the category `foobar` I had to use:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=4&per_page=1
```

To get 100 posts associated with the category `foobar` I used:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=4&per_page=100
```

and as I found out and it was also mentioned in the [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/308869/25271) my logic of using `-1` was incorrect, you can only use 1 to 100.  As it was discussed in the comment on what to do if there are more than 100 posts, well you can call the page using `offset` and I found that under the documentation [Pagination](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/#pagination-parameters):

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=4&offset=10&per_page=1
```

so to get more than 100 you'd to build a loop in whatever language you wanted and push it to a file.  To assist with the looping under `/wp-json/wp/v2/categories/` and when you reference the category you can reference the total count under `count` which is below the `id`.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much all the URLs you are using are invalid in some way:

```
http://foobar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/categories_name=hello
```

`categories_name` is not a [valid argument](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#arguments) for listing posts, and even if it was you are missing the `?` part of the query string.

```
http://foobar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/categories_name=hello?per_page=‌​1
```

This one is also missing the `?`. Query parameters on a URL, which the API uses for its arguments, need to start with `?`, with `&` for additional parameters. A correctly formatted query string looks like this:

```
http://domain.com/path/?argument=value&argument2=value2
```

So this one:

```
http://foobar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/categories_name=hello&per_page=‌​1
```

Is also missing the `?` but you've used `&` correctly this time (though are still using the invalid `categories_name` argument).

This one:

```
http://foobar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?per_page=‌​1$categories_name=hello
```

Is using a `$` for some reason. That's not a valid way to separate parameters in a query string (and still using the invalid `categories_name` argument).

This one *is* correct:

```
http://foobar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?categories=4&per_page=‌​1
```

But based on your comment:

> I thought I might be able to use -1 similar to the development of a
>   theme but I get an error.

It sounds like you *actually* tried:

```
http://foobar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?categories=4&per_page=‌​-1
```

Which *won't* work, because `-1` is an invalid value. You can only retrieve between `1` and `100` results with the API.

Comment: Ya I found out why it wasn't working I need to reference the 'id' of the category now I need to figure out how to get 100 posts after the first 100.  The API won't do me any good if I can't figure out how to successfully pull these posts for a react powered theme.

Comment: 100 at a time is a lot of posts. It's the max but that doesn't mean its a good idea to query all of them at once. Either way, you combine `per_page` with `page`. So `per_page=20` will get the first 20, then `per_page=20&page=2` will get the next 20. It's the responsibility of your application to keep track of whether there's enough posts for a 2nd page.

Answer (score 1):

When doing "per_page" on the products/categories endpoint, the MAX you can use is 100. Anything more then that will cause the error Error: Invalid parameter(s): per_page [rest_invalid_param]